# Two vsftpd instances - check passive port on FTPS

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, vsftp

I have configured VSFTPD in a CentOS machine to run on two instances, with vsftpd.conf and vsftpd2.conf. Here is the content of the second conf file:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
chroot_local_user=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ftpd_banner=Hello.
listen=YES
listen_port=30
local_enable=YES
local_umask=022
pam_service_name=vsftpd
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_address=192.168.100.162
pasv_max_port=389
pasv_min_port=389
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/user_conf
userlist_enable=NO
write_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog2
xferlog_std_format=NO
dual_log_enable=YES
log_ftp_protocol=YES
```

The first conf file is identical excepting the xferlog file, the listen_port that is missing, and the pasv_max_port/pasv_min_port that are 65000/60000

So I have one FTPS working on port 21 and the other on port 30. Both are working fine, but I want to make sure that 389 is really being used. So, I started a session with Wireshark, where I could see all my TCP packets to port 30, but no one to 389. Instead, I see packets to my remote server on port 49276.

How can I make sure that this is working fine?

Comment: I don't know if this question should be in Serverfault instead of the Unix site, as the first one has 359 questions tagged vsftpd, and this one only 60.

Comment: I've noticed that VSFTPD does not takes into account pasv_max_port and pasv_min_port into account when the number is too low:
I've tried 30000 for both, and it works well. I've tried 389 for both, and it's takes some high range port. I've also tried 389-399, and it's the same `227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,100,162,22,29)`

Answer (score 0):

I just got from other source vsftpd is not able to reserve ports below 1024 for PASV

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-ftp-vsftpd-conf.html

I will mark the question as readed, as we don't need to inspect TCP packets, as with a FTP client we are able to see the PASV command. Example for 30000

```
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,100,162,117,48)
```